# Getting issues in object oriented perl

Tags: perl

I am new to OO perl. I am trying to write one simple program but getting the error.

Created a  package Employee.pm as

```
package Employee;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub get_names {
    my $self = @_;
    print " getting the names \n";
    return $self;
}

sub set_names {
    my ($self, $last_name) = @_;
    $self->{last_name} = $last_name;
    return $self->{$last_name};
}
1;
```

And created a .pl file as

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Employee;

my $obj = new Employee("name" => "nitesh", "last_name" => "Goyal");

my $val = $obj->get_names();

print %$val;

my $setName = $obj->set_names("kumar");

print "$setName \n";
```

I am getting error as

```
"Can't use string ("1") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at class1.txt line   10."
```

Comment: One another query : Like in "sub get_names" we are declaring $self = @_ , and in the calling script we are passing as $obj->get_names(). Why no arguments need to give while calling when we have done $self = @_ in the sub.

Comment: Please do not correct your code in the question. If you remove your errors, our answers will look pretty strange. If you have new questions about your code, ask a new question. This one is asked and answered now.

Comment: It is my mistake. Really sorry. Next time it will not happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

```
"Can't use string ("1") as a HASH ref ..
```

Comes from this part:

```
sub get_names {
    my $self = @_;
```

When an array is put in scalar context, it returns its size. Since you call the sub with

```
$obj->get_names();
```

Only one argument is passed, which is the object, so `@_` contains 1 argument, and its size is 1, therefore in the sub `get_names`, the variable `$self` is set to 1. Hence the error. What you probably should do is

```
my $self = shift;
```

But then, that will not do anything, because you never stored the names in your constructor. As `mpapec` said, you should do

```
my $self = { @_ };
```

in the constructor sub `new`.

Also, in `get_names`, you simply return the object, which is not very useful. You should perhaps return `$self->{name}` and `$self->{last_name}`.

Comment: thanks. But what does this mean "But then, that will not do anything, because you never stored the names in your constructor. As mpapec said, you should do"

Comment: When you called `new` you never stored the arguments anywhere. You only stored an empty hash ref, `{}`.

Comment: TLP i have modified the code. get_names is working but now set_names i giving error as "Use of uninitialized value $setName in concatenation (.) or string at class1.txt
 line 15."

Comment: That is because you set `$self->{last_name}`, but you return `$self->{$last_name}`.

Comment: TLP : Your knowledge is really admirable. Can you suggest good books in perl

Comment: One another query : Like in "sub get_names" we are declaring $self = @_ , and in the calling script we are passing as $obj->get_names(). Why no arguments need to give while calling when we have done $self = shift; in the sub.

Comment: @Nitesh Thank you. No, not really, as I have never read any books on Perl, only the documentation.

Comment: @Nitesh If you did `$self = @_` then you have not understood my answer, and I encourage you to read that part again.

Comment: sorry its a typo. I did $self = shift;. It the old message that i  copied

Comment: @Nitesh You do not need to supply arguments to `get_names` because you are getting the names from the object, and the object is stored in `$obj`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks for your time and patience and your excellent skills of explaining things in a simple way :)